# Debugging on ART is gruesomely slow, switching to Dalvik not an option

Tags: android, dalvik, google-project-tango

I'm not sure whether Tango even works with Dalvik, and switching back to Dalvik from ART seems the most common suggestion for issues with debug performance -  running the point cloud test in debug mode is fundamentally pointless, it runs too slowly for any real work -  what am I missing -  I can't see how GOOG debugged any of the demo apps with what I've encountered  :-(

Comment: Mark, what type of performance debugging you are referring to? Is there a tool that requires delvik to run? But in short, Tango won't work on Delvik..

Comment: rats rats rats - see latest post - I now have the dreaded debugger death on ART - but I am switching back notheless - probably would be a good thing to stop others from trying to work with dalvik - side note, tango is not happy, but sometimes it comes up just fine - yeah, I know .... tough   :-)

Answer (score 1):

After a certain amount of misery on a Windows platform, this is the solution I've come up with - other factors were also involved, such as getting my hands on the actual image pixels so I can colorize the point cloud and texture the generated surfaces.

1) Use Android Studio for Java, use Visual Studio + VisualGDB (this thing is wonderful!) for C/C++

2) The Visual Studio project rules, i.e. it physically contains all of the files

3) I use cygwin, therefore I can make it so that the Android Studio project is just a giant collection of links to the java bits and ndk output.  I use Android Studio to debug java, have access to nice layout editors, etc.  Its not quite mature yet, and this is a good fit for it.

4) I do all the heavy lifting in C++ in the native part - as things should be if you're chucking around this much data.  I do have lifters for things like images and pointclouds, as java is better suited to phoning these things home as json to webservices

5) I DON'T debug Java and C++ simultaneously.  I'm cool with that.

6) C side debugger performance is awesome!

7) Jury is still out on the Java side,  but since the computationally expensive stuff is out of the way, that's a lot nicer picture.

It was a long strange trip, but if you're on windows, and aware that the key element of this solution costs money, there is at least an opening in the tunnel - I am planning on looking at the nVidia stuff later,  would love to hear if someone beats me to it.

Comment: I too had started to go down this path.  Editing C files in Android Studio was slow & feature-deficient.  Visual Studio is great for general editing and maintenance of source code.  Thanks for the tip about VisualGDB.  I was going to make my code compile for both windows and android using "#ifdef WIN32 ... #else ... #endif" conditionals, and a post-build for "ndk-build".  But this looks a lot better.

Comment: If you're on a budget, the nVidia Tegra tool chain works well too - and its free, once they grant you access